# Interoperability in DDS

Tags: data-distribution-service

I am new to DDS domain and need to have the below understanding.

how to publish common topics between two vendors to achieve interoperability in DDS?

The Scenario is :
Suppose there are two vendor products V1 and V2. V1 has a publisher which publishes on topic T1. V2 wants to subscribe for this topic.How will the Subscriber(V2) know that there exists a Topic T1?

I have a similar doubt on Domain level.how will a subscriber know to which domain it has to participate in?

I am using OpenDDS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Interoperability between vendors is possible, and regularly tested/demonstrated by the main vendors.

You will need to configure your DDS implementation to use RTPS ( I think RTPS2 currently), rather than any proprietary transport that vendors may use. This might be enabled by default.

In terms of which domain to participate in, you programmatically create a domain participant in a particular domain (which domain it connects to might be controlled by a config file) and all further entities (publishers, subscribers, etc) that you create then belong to that domain participant and therefore operate in that domain

Answer (score 1):

To build on @rcs's answer a bit... the actual amount of work you have to do can depend on DDS implementations (OpenDDS, RTI, Prismtech...) because they'll have different defaults. If you use the same on both ends, then your configuration becomes a lot simpler since defaults should line up for things like domain and RTPS.

You will need to make sure the following match:

- Domain ID
- Domain Partion
- Transport (I recommend RTPS, FWIW version difference between 2.1 and 2.2 hasn't mattered in my experience)
- TCP or UDP
- Discovery port and data port - this will matter more or less depending which implementations you use and whether or not you're using the same one on both ends of the connection, if use using the same, they'll have the same defaults.
- Make sure the topic one publishes matches the topic the other subscribes to, this will apply to the Topic and the Type ([see more here](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.2.3/doc/manuals/connext_dds/html_files/RTI_ConnextDDS_CoreLibraries_UsersManual/Content/UsersManual/DDS_Samples__Instances__and_Keys.htm))
- Serialization of the data
- Discovery (unicast vs. multicast, make sure
  whatever setup you choose is valid, ex: both devices are in the same
  multicast group)
- QoS settings will need to line up, though I think defaults will likely work ([read more here](http://download.prismtech.com/docs/Vortex/html/ospl/DDSTutorial/qos.html))
- Get the Shapes demo working between the machines you're working on first, this does some basic sanity checking to know that it is possible with the given configuration and network setup. Every vendor/implementation that I've seen has a shapes demo to run, for example, [here is RTI's](https://www.rti.com/shapes-demo).

That's all I can think of right now, hope that helps. I have found DDS documentation to be really good, especially if you know when you can (and when you can't) use any vendor's documentation's answer for your implementation (ex: answer found on RTI's doc or forum and whether or not it works for your OpenDDS application). Often the solutions are similar, but you'll find RTI supports the most and RTI + Prismtech have some of the best documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The DDS RTPS protocol exchanges discovery information so that different applications participating in the same domain (!) know who is out there, and what they are offering/requesting. You need to make sure that the two applications are using the same domain ID (specified on the domain participant). Also, as some implementations allow for different transport options, make sure to use RTPS (sometimes called DDSI) networking.

The RTPS specification contains a mapping from domain ID to port numbers, so if applications from different vendors use the same ID it should just work. Implementations might however override portnumbers with configuration.

To maximize the chance that the applications communicate properly, ensure they use the same IDL datamodel. Vendors have different approaches to type evolution / mapping types that don't exactly match, and not all of them implement the XTypes specification (yet).

Also, as some implementations are stricter than others, ensure that you stay within bounds of the specification. This means that a topic name should only contain alphanumerical characters (I sometimes see ':' to indicate scoping, that is not allowed).

Things that will definitely not work between vendors is TRANSIENT/PERSISTENT durability or communication over TCP, as both have not been standardized yet. TRANSIENT_LOCAL should work. The difference between TRANSIENT_LOCAL and TRANSIENT is that with TRANSIENT_LOCAL, data is no longer aligned after a publisher (writer) leaves the system, whereas with TRANSIENT that data will still be available.

Also note that for API-level interoperability between vendors, your best chance is to use the new isocpp API, since that one has been implemented pretty consistently across the vendor implementations I've seen.

Hope that helps!